# Python MySQLdb not returning the result of last query?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

So I have a function using MySQLdb:

```
def getUserPoints(uid):
    qServer.execute("SELECT points FROM TS3_STAMM_1 WHERE ts3_uid=%s", (uid,))
    qConn.commit()
    r = int(qServer.fetchall()[0][0])
    return r
```

which returns a single unsigned int.

Now two things happen:
if I leave out the `qConn.commit()` it will always return the same value, even though the value on the mySQL database changed. (But isnt the commit call just for changing things?)

And also, for some reason the query returns the same value as last query if there hasnt been a query for that exact entry for over 10 minutes. But after querying a second time like a second later, it returns the new value.

Why is that? Is it an issue with [my code](https://github.com/WhOoKie/ts3stamm/blob/master/ts3stamm_leveling.py) or the query? Maybe there is a cache which isnt cleared and returned on the second time?

I also tried just running the query twice, but there is still the same problem.
Also getting rid of the commit call doesn't change anything, and fetching twice doesn't change it either.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

Comment: You might find [these notes](https://gist.github.com/mindriot101/664924f7a0e4e961aea9) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default with mysql-python is autocommit=False. That means that your queries implicitly start transactions and you need to explicity call commit to commit changes to the database.

If you are running with the REPEATABLE READ isolation level, you won't see changes from other transactions. When you call `getUserPoints`, the first select is in the old transaction so you get the old value. Then the transaction is committed, so you get the updated value when you call `getUserPoints` again.

The autocommit=False behaviour can be unintuitive. Django, for example, defaults to autocommit=True, and [they recommend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#mysql-isolation-level) the READ COMMITTED isolation level instead of REPEATABLE READ (the default for MySQL).

Comment: So you're saying that I should change my Isolation Level to READ COMMITTED? Or what would be the best option to query about 120 querys at once and then leave it for an hour?

Comment: You should definitely consider changing to autocommit=True and changing the isolation level to READ COMMITTED. I wouldn't go as far as saying you should make those changes. You need to think through possible effects. For example if you change to `autocommit=True`, it's up to you to explicitly start transactions when required.

Comment: So I have to call `qServer.execute("START TRANSACTION")` everytime I change something? Or is that just an example for a query?

Comment: This is getting off topic. No, if you change to `autocommit=True` then your queries will be automatically committed. If you have two queries that you want to run in a transaction (e.g. they should both succeed or they should both be rolled back), then it would be up to you to start and commit/rollback the transaction.